# How to create a template class with a constructor (with parameters) and pass a method of the class to a thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, templates

I want to create a template class that incapsulate a vector. The constructor of the class receive an int size as parameter. In the class there's a method to push an element into the vector. In the main I want to pass this push() to a thread

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

template <class T> class Queue{
private:
int size;
vector<T> v;
public:
Queue(int size) {
    this->size = size;
}

void push(T t) {
    v.push_back(t);
 }
};

int main()
{
Queue<int> * miaCoda = new Queue(4);
thread t1(&Queue::push, miaCoda, 2);
t1.join();
}
```

I get all this error in the first 2 lines of the main

Error   C2514   'Queue': class has no constructors
Error   C2955   'Queue': use of class template requires template argument list
Error   C2661   'std::thread::thread': no overloaded function takes 3 arguments 
Error (active)  E0441   argument list for class template "Queue" is missing
Error (active)  E0289   no instance of constructor "std::thread::thread" matches the argument list

Answer (score 3):

```
Queue<int> * miaCoda = new Queue(4);
thread t1(&Queue::push, miaCoda, 2);
```

`Queue` is not a class. It is a template. What is a class, here, is `Queue<int>`. Now that's a class, with full rights and privileges thereof.

It follows that to get a pointer to a class method, well, you have to specify the class whose method you need to get a pointer to:

```
thread t1(&Queue<int>::push, miaCoda, 2);
```

Comment: When I was learning, I thought of it as "Queue is a compile-time function that _returns_ a class, and the parameters to this function are wrapped in `<>`".  So `Queue<int>` is a compile time function call that returns the class.